# Finding a double-peak function that decomposes into a dot product of two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Sorry that the title is a bit vague, but here's the formal definition of the problem.

**The problem**

Given an integer $N$, denote $[N]= \{ 1,2,\dots,N \} $. I need to find a function $f:([N], [N], [N]) \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, an integer $D$ and a real value $A$ such that:

1. For all $i,j\in [N]$, $f(i,j,x) \geq A$ if and only if $x=i$ or $x=j$.
2. There exists functions $g:([N], [N]) \mapsto \mathbb{R}^D_{\geq 0}$ and $h:[N] \mapsto \mathbb{R}^D_{\geq 0}$, where $\mathbb{R}^D_{\geq 0}$ is the set of non-negative vectors in $D$ dimensions, such that

$$ f(i,j,x) = g(i,j)^T h(x), \forall i,j,x\in [N]. $$

Essentially, what I need is a function $f(i,j,x)$ that can be decomposed into the inner product of two functions $g(i,j)$ and $h(x)$, so that the former only depends on $i$ and $j$, and the latter only depends on $x$. Additionally, if we treat $i,j$ as parameters and $x$ as input, then $f$ has exactly two "peaks" with values above $A$ on $[N]$, at $x=i$ and $x=j$.

**An example, if we allow $g$ and $h$ to be negative**

Suppose we allow $g$ and $h$ to just be any vector in $\mathbb{R}^D$. Then, one construction that solves the problem is:

$$ f(i,j,x) = -(x-i)^2 (x-j)^2 $$

Which is simplified to

$$ f(i,j,x) = -x^4 + 2(i+j)x^3 - (i^2+4ij+j^2) x^2 + 2(i^2 j + j^2 i)x - i^2 j^2 $$

So it can be decomposed as $g(i,j) = \left( 1, i+j, -(i^2+4ij+j^2), i^2j+j^2i, -i^2j^2 \right)$ and $h(x)=\left(-x^4,2x^3,x^2,2x,1\right)$.

This doesn't solve the original problem because some entries of $g(i,j)$ and $h(x)$ are negative on $[N]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: We managed to solve the question by ourselves.

The solution is to add constant terms to $g(i,j)$ and $h(x)$, that do not depend on $x$, so that all entries become non-negative. Namely (with a bit of reorganization and moving constants around from the question):

$$ g'(i,j) = \left( 1, i+j, i^2+4ij+j^2, i^2j+j^2i, i^2 j^2 \right)$$
$$ h(x) = \left( N^4-x^4, 2x^3, N^2-x^2, 2x, 0 \right)$$

This means

$$ f'(i,j,x) = g'(i,j)^T h(x) = -(x-i)^2 (x-j)^2 + N^4 + N^2 (i^2+4ij+j^2) + i^2 j^2 $$

All terms except the first one do not depend on $x$, so for fixed $i,j$, $f'$ has exactly two peaks, $x=i$ and $x=j$.

Now we just need to make all peaks have the same value that does not depend on $i,j$. This can be done by scaling:

$$ g(i,j) = \frac{g(i,j)}{N^4 + N^2 (i^2+4ij+j^2) + i^2 j^2} $$

Which allows us to simply set $A=1$.